# JAVA_HOME was unexpected at this time

Tags: java, gradle

When I'm trying to run gradle I get

> JAVA_HOME was unexpected at this time.

error. I have set the JAVA_HOME and when I try to run a java project successfully runs but when I try to run gradle I get this error.I'll be thankful if anyone can help me.

```
C:\Users\Milad>java -version
java version "10" 2018-03-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10+46)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10+46, mixed mode)
```

I have defined JAVA_HOME in environment variable as below

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10

Comment: You will have to provide more context.

Comment: what should I provide?

Comment: Is your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable defined?

Comment: Which task in Gradle are you trying to run? Is there a stack trace? If not you could try to add `--stacktrace` to the command line.

Comment: Apparently some script somewhere (maybe Gradle) is trying to set this variable, but is failing to do so. You need to debug your codebase. Start with finding JAVA_HOME string in your code base itself...

Comment: I have already defined JAVA_HOME environment variable

Comment: Verify JAVA_HOME is set correctly. Try running `%JAVA_HOME%/bin/javac.exe`

Comment: This sounds like a parser error. Can you post your `build.gradle`, or try to run gradle on another project?

Comment: In windows system, when install JDK, it will copy the java executable files to "C:\Windows\System32" folder, or the  "javapath" soft link for win10, like "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java", you can check this and remove all of them and let your "JAVA_HOME" available.